# Turn off n-p-n BJT on non-zero voltage

Tags: microcontroller, led, bjt

I have a controller that uses 0.2V voltage as logical zero and 0.4V as a logical one and want to turn a LED on/off depending on these two levels.

I've built a cicrcuit like one below and tried to choose R1 value to turn the transistor off when control voltage is low, but it was eather always open and control voltage was only affecting LED's brightless, or (with big R1) it was always off.

Maybe I'm missing something or some other circuit should be used?

How to solve my problem and turn the LED on/off using 0.2/0.4V control voltage levels?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked on-line to see what voltage a BJT needs on the base to start meaningful conduction? Maybe look at the data sheet for the device?

Comment: If you could find a germanium transistor you might stand a chance.

Comment: A guaranteed method would use a comparator to determine if the logic level is low or high.

Comment: I do believe the problem is somewhere else... what is excactly your driver? Nothing in this world outputs something like that. I do belive you are average-measuring some PWM or other pulse driven stuff.

Comment: @carloc I was measuring a value generated by RC transmitter and you're probably right, it's averaged PWM. So sad to be an idiot like me. :) So I need something like filter and comparator. Thank you for pointing me in a right direction.

Comment: C'mon don be too hard to yourself, it's just a common error among beginners, in any field, overlook something you probably are not aware at all. It just sounded too strange to me

Answer (score 4):

Here is a circuit idea that can translate the 0.2V -> 0.4V signal to an on/off signal for the LED.

[image]

The two PNP transistors create a differential pair to act as a comparator. The left side takes in the input signal and the right side compares to a reference of ~0.3V created via a voltage divider across a forward biased diode. The load resistor (R6) on the right leg of the differential pair develops a voltage swing of near 0V to just over 1V which works well to switch the output NPN driver transistor on and off.

The circuit works in simulation but can likely be optimized to lower over all current draw on the power source. As shown the LED current is 9mA and the full circuit current draw is ~32 to 41mA. A sizeable chunk of that is going to heavily bias the diode.

Comment: what's the role of D1 in your circuit? @Michael Karas

Comment: @dirac16 - D1 is already described in the text. Used as a low voltage reference based upon its forward voltage drop. In this circuit as shown the R4 allows about 20mA through the diode to forward bias it.

Comment: yeah, 0.75/1.75*0.7=0.3V that is what you wanted on the base of Q2. That was pretty easy to see. Sorry, and thanks anyway @Michael Karas

Comment: This was the very first thought I had. Glad to see an incarnation posted here.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic problem is that a BJT needs about 600-700 mV B-E before it starts conducting meaningful current.  One solution is to bias the transistor so that the 200 mV difference is right at the B-E voltage that makes a large difference in current:

[image]

R1 and R2 form a voltage divider that creates about 820 mV from the 5 V supply.  When the input signal is 200 mV, this puts 620 mV across B-E, which should cause some collector current to flow.  When the input is 400 mV, then there is only 420 mV B-E, which will cause very little collector current to flow.  This collector current is then amplified by Q2 and again by Q3, at which time it's strong enough to drive the LED.

There are some additional wrinkles to get around the fact that Q1 won't act as a nice on/off switch.  It will have some leakage when the input is 400 mV.  R4 is intended to require some minimum Q1 collector current before Q2 turns on.

Another trick is hysteresis, which is what R5 provides.  This is positive feedback that turns Q1 on more when it's already on, and less when its already off.  It provides snap action instead of a soft transition region where the LED fades on and off.

Adjust R1 to set the threshold between on and off.  Adjust R5 so that the hysteresis "dead zone" is maybe half the input voltage swing, which would be 100 mV.

I posted this circuit only to show one way that the B-E voltage threshold of BJTs can be overcome.  Another would be in the classic comparator configuration.  However, regardless of all these, I'd probably use a real comparator if actually faced with this problem.  It would be simpler and more reliable across temperature and voltage fluctuations.

Comment: Last evening I was just about to post another circuit that looked almost exactly like this one!.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the kind of circuit that would usually be used- it uses half of U1, an [LM393](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/group1/b4/cc/cf/13/18/28/44/f5/CD00000465/files/CD00000465.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000465.pdf), which is an inexpensive dual comparator in an 8-pin package (available from multiple manufacturers):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN76eC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> How to solve my problem and turn the LED on/off using 0.2/0.4V control voltage levels?

two ways:

1. amplify it to a more usable level.
2. use a comparator.

Answer (score -3):

Try with somewhat large value of R1 or decrease level of logic zero some more.

Comment: Have you also considered the Vbe threshold voltage of a 2N2222 NPN transistor?